# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens,should match

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I new to PHP and learning on how to use prepared statements and getting the error listed in the title. I looked at previous peoples' problems in regards to this error, but the problems and solutions seem to complex for me to use their solutions to try to solve my problem. I want to grab users input sanitize it and then execute the query and hopefully minimize the chance of an SQL injection.

Can someone kindly look at my code.

```
sth=$conn->prepare("SELECT EnglishWord FROM Japanesedefinition WHERE Japaneseword =:Japaneseword");
$sth->execute(array(':Japaneseword',$name));
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 $result ->EnglishWord;
```

in my bind constructor I am $name is set to $_POST['Japanseword']. Thought I might mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the array should be `key=>value`, not `key,value`.

```
$sth->execute(array(":Japaneseword"=>$name));
```

Comment: You're correct it worked.I can't give you credit until 5 minutes.Why?

Comment: @Saori, I think the delay is to (slightly) discourage rushed answers. This particular question only requires a short contribution, but in general we like detail here `:)`.